# is "We go to same school" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> When a school is being referred to as an institution, you do not need
>   to use **the**: **When do the children finish school**? When you are
>   talking about a particular building, **the** is used: **I’ll meet you
>   outside the school**.  Prison, jail, court, and church work in the same
>   way: **Her husband spent three years in prison**. [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/school_1?q=school)

These are not wrong: "**We go to school**" &  "**We go to the same school**".

My question is that whether we can say: "**We go to same school?**". I can feel that is wrong but not sure.

Comment: In "We go to school." *school* is a descriptive term regarding an activity (getting an education). I doesn't refer to a physical location.

Comment: @user3169 If you follow that description too closely, though, you'll run into issues. "You want to borrow Dad's car after supper? Where are you going?" — "To school." Or similarly: "Every morning I get up, eat breakfast, and walk three blocks to school." Even if the activity is meant, those sentences certainly put the accent on the physical location.

Comment: @LukeSawczak  In such cases the activity happens to be at a physical location. Its a fine distinction.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I don't think that's problematic here.  "Where are you going? / To school." is just simplifying the conversation.  The specific school is known, so it can be assumed from context.  It would not be wrong to say "To the school here" (indeed, I go "to the university", but I don't "go to school" since I teach there, and am not a student there).

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Where are you taking the car? — To school. Although I admit that the activity aspect can fit here, I think the physical location one is the prominent one. I don't want to say the distinction isn't useful; I just want to ensure the OP isn't therefore led to say "To the school" here because of the prominence of the "move from one place to another" idea in sentences like this.

Comment: @LukeSawczak This may require some pondering by me, but we use a similar usage with *work*, e.g. "I am taking the car to work", even though I mean a specific job.  "Work" and "school" (and probably a few other nouns" serve as somewhat neutral locations that don't require elaboration, even though in some contexts specificity is intended.  If you asked me where I was, so you could drop off something to me, I might say "at work" because I know that you know where this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To go to school* means to be a student. The *singular **school** without determiner* has that meaning.

As soon as you add the adjective **same** in front of "school", you're referring to a particular place (not to being a student) and so an article is needed.

We cannot say:

I like same movie.

I visit same restaurant.

I like same girl.

I go to same school.

You must say "*the* same" + noun.

Comment: What about "Sorcha isn’t at our school". "School" in that sentence is defined or not?

Comment: @Tom: **at** refers to the place.  **our** is a possessive determiner. So it's referring to a particular school.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't say *we go to same school*. You can say *we go to school* because you are not specifying what exact school you go to. You are speaking in general. But when you say *we go to the same school*, there is a specific school that you both go to. The word *same* there does the specifying for you.

Likewise, if you say *we go to **the** school* then we know you are talking about a specific school that you have probably mentioned previously. And if you say *her husband spent three years in **the** prison* then there is a specific prison location that you are talking about.